# How to implement procedure to create document with header and lines in 2 different tables SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on an android application for inventory. It has an Sql Server Database. I have to tables like:

```
  InventoryHeader
  [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [transactionumber] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
  [storeroom] [varchar](15) NULL,
  [transactiontype] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
  [projectname] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [projectid] [int] NULL,
  [comments] [varchar](250) NULL,
  [addedBy] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
  [date] [datetime] NOT NULL

  Inventorylines
  [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [transactionumber] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
  [linenumber] [int] NOT NULL,
  [storeroom] [varchar](15) NULL,
  [locationtype] [varchar](10) NULL,
  [storeroomlocationid] [int] NULL,
  [itemnum] [varchar](20) NULL,
  [quantity] [decimal](10, 3) NULL,
  [uom] [varchar](10) NULL,
  [unitprice] [decimal](10, 3) NULL,
  [lineprice] [decimal](10, 3) NULL
```

Which is the best way to make an api to create a document with header and one or more lines? I managed to create a procedure to create the header of the document but not the lines. Any suggestions?

Here is the procedure I have:

```
`CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddNewInventoryTr]
   @Transactionumber            varchar(30)             , 
   @Storeroom                   varchar(15)     ,
   @Transactiontype             VArchar(15)     ,
   @Projectname                 VArchar(50)     ,
   @Comments                    varchar(250)    , 
   @Addedby                     varchar(20)     ,
   @Date                        datetime

  AS
  BEGIN
  DECLARE  @Projectid int 



   exec @Projectid = projectidproc @Projectname,  @Projectid output


    INSERT INTO inventoryheader(transactionumber,storeroom, transactiontype, 
    projectname, projectid, comments, addedBy,date)



 VALUES(@Transactionumber,@Storeroom, 
 @Transactiontype,@Projectname,@Projectid , @Comments,@Addedby  ,@Date)
 END
 GO`
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing creating the lines ? Can you share the query that you used for that ?

Comment: I don't know if i shoul make an while loop for creating lines in sql or to make them in api with dapper :)

Comment: you can create another Stored Procedure to insert into the lines and call it from your application

Comment: and send an object for every line? correct?